# Link text replace by list text

Tags: jquery

In this given example i need "Choose answer" text should replace with clicked list, for ex. if i click on "Choose answer 1" it should replace with "I. Bridge".

```js
$('.sbSelector').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this).closest('.sbHolder').find('.sbOptions');
  $('.sbOptions').not($this).slideUp();
  $this.slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.sbSelector {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sbOptions {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sbHolder">
  <a href="#" class="sbSelector">Choose answer 1</a>
  <ul class="sbOptions">
    <li><a href="#">Choose answer 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">I. Bridge</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">II. Nut</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">III. Neck</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="sbHolder">
  <a href="#" class="sbSelector">Choose answer 2</a>
  <ul class="sbOptions">
    <li><a href="#">Choose answer 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">I. Bridge</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">II. Nut</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">III. Neck</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="sbHolder">
  <a href="#" class="sbSelector">Choose answer 3</a>
  <ul class="sbOptions">
    <li><a href="#">Choose answer 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">I. Bridge</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">II. Nut</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">III. Neck</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind **[`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)** event handler to list  item and based on the clicked list item update the content.

```js
$('.sbSelector').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this).closest('.sbHolder').find('.sbOptions');
  $('.sbOptions').not($this).slideUp();
  $this.slideToggle('slow');
});

$('.sbOptions li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default click event action
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.closest('ul') // get parent ul
    .prev() // get the `a` tag which is to be updated
    .text($this.text()); // update the content
})
```

```css
.sbSelector {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sbOptions {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sbHolder">
  <a href="#" class="sbSelector">Choose answer 1</a>
  <ul class="sbOptions">
    <li><a href="#">Choose answer 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">I. Bridge</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">II. Nut</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">III. Neck</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="sbHolder">
  <a href="#" class="sbSelector">Choose answer 2</a>
  <ul class="sbOptions">
    <li><a href="#">Choose answer 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">I. Bridge</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">II. Nut</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">III. Neck</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="sbHolder">
  <a href="#" class="sbSelector">Choose answer 3</a>
  <ul class="sbOptions">
    <li><a href="#">Choose answer 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">I. Bridge</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">II. Nut</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">III. Neck</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```